# Schedule Post on Facebook in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app i want to post on Facebook for later date.I know how to post on Facebook wall, but Is there any method to schedule a post on Facebook automatically if the time specified has reached?

Answer (score 0):

I think **NO** there is no method to do so because when you `POST` or `GET` on facebook you need a valid `access token` which you append with `URL` string, `access token` is generate many times because its have expire date. After some time interval it expires and you need an another `access token` to `POST` and `GET` again.
So in your case `access token` would be expire and you cant `POST` anything surely you would get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

From my little knowledge, you can use **NSTimer** class for it. I think there is no other way

You can use its  Instance Methods or Class Methods to do it.

Please refer the details from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Example:

**initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:**

**setFireDate:**

**scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:**

**scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:**